# Can a SharedPreferences.Editor be reused?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Can a `SharedPreferences.Editor` be safely reused? In other words, can I have this declared once in my class:

```
val editor = prefs.edit()
```

and then use its `apply()` method multiple times, like this?

```
editor.putString("myString", "Some string").apply()

// some time later...
editor.putInt("myInt", 682).apply()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can reuse it and then use its `apply()` method multiple times to save the values.

I see that you are using Kotlin, is the same as in Java/Android SDK.